# Flutter - Dynamically assign RegEx value

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have few number of programmatically generated TextFields in the `ListView.builder` and I'm trying to pass dynamic regEx value to `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(dynamicRegEx))`, but it is not working, it is not even accepting any characters. If I pass the actual value, like, `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[^.-]*'))`, it works. But every TextField will have different set of accepting characters. Below is the code I tried so far. Can somebody help me passing dynamic regex variable

```dart
ListView.builder(
  key: Key('builder $selectedENP'),
  itemCount: namePlates.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      iconColor: _selectedTheme.primaryColorDark,
      collapsedIconColor: _selectedTheme.primaryColorDark,
      backgroundColor: _selectedTheme.primaryColorLight,
      key: Key(i.toString()),
      initiallyExpanded: i == selectedENP,
      collapsedTextColor: _selectedTheme.primaryColorDark,
      title: Text(
        namePlates[i].title,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "Raleway",
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: _buildExpandableContent(i),
        )
      ],
      onExpansionChanged: (value) {
        if (value) {
          setState(() {
            changeButtonState(i);
            selectedENP = i;
            print("Selected ENP: $selectedENP");
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            selectedENP = -1;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Below is the buildExpandableContent method

```
_buildExpandableContent(int selectedENPIndex) {
    List<Widget> columnContent = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < namePlates[selectedENPIndex].contents.length; i++) {
      TextEditingController dynamicController = TextEditingController();

      //var allowedCharacters = 'r\'^[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*\''; \\ If I pass this also doesn't work
      var allowedCharacters = namePlates[selectedENPIndex].acceptingString[i]; // Passing this also doesn't work
     
      columnContent.add(Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 10),
        child: TextFormField(
          maxLength: 16,
          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(allowedCharacters)) // <- dynamic variable
          ],
          controller: dynamicController,
          
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: const UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: namePlates[selectedENPIndex].contents[i],
            hintText: namePlates[selectedENPIndex].acceptingString[i],
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
    columnContent.add(const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
    ));

    return columnContent;
  }
}
```

Model

```
List<ENP> namePlates = [
  ENP(
    'Order Details',
    [
      'Alpha-numeric, space and dot',
      'Alpha-numeric and space',
      'only numeric',
      'only numeric'
    ],
    ['Model', 'Project Name', 'Order Number', 'Works Number'],
    [
      'r\'^[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*\'',
      'r\'^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*\'',
      'r\'^[0-9]*\'',
      'r\'^[0-9]*\''
    ],
  )
]
```

Comment: Please format the code properly and provide more info on what works and doesn't work. Also, I couldn't understand the question

Comment: Why are you trying to assign Regular Expressions dynamically? Is there a particular reason? You should fully state the reason why you are doing something

Comment: @Noah If you see the model, there is title (Order Details) , accepting characters (['Alpha-numeric, space and dot',....] goes as textfield hint,  ['model', 'project name'...] based on this array, number of textfields will be programmatically created,  in this case 4 textfields will be created..and each textfield should accept certain characters, that is defined in the next list ['r\'^[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*\'', ....]. So I'm trying to pass the first reg ex ('r\'^[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*\'') to 'Model' textfield and so on..

Comment: FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*')) -> This works, but all the textfield will accept same regex.

 FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(allowedCharacters)) -> This Doesn't work:
You can see how value of allowedCharacters are assigned in the second code block

          ],

Answer (score 0):

Try converting array of regex to the array of RegExp and use it for the further process

```
var regexList = <RegExp>[
    RegExp('r\'^[a-zA-Z0-9. ]*\''),
    RegExp('r\'^[0-9]*\'')
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: regexList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var dynamicController = TextEditingController();
          RegExp validation = regexList.elementAt(index);
          return TextFormField(
            maxLength: 16,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(validation),
            ],
            controller: dynamicController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```